# How to expose table widget to presenter in MVP pattern with gwt

Tags: gwt, mvp

In MVP pattern the widget (the view) exposes its widgets in form like this:

```
@Override    
public HasClickHandlers getAddIssueClickHandlers() {
            return addIssueButton;
        }
```

and like:

```
@Override
public HasText getTaskName() {
    return taskName; // taskName is a Label
}
```

To allow the presenter to modify the view or get the values from a widget. However, its uncertain how to get a table widget, like FlexTable or CellTable in order for the presenter to modify the table. Any ideas is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all GWT widgets were designed with these interfaces (i.e. **HasclickHandlers**, **HasText**, **IsWidget**, etc) in mind.
In recent GWT versions the basic widgets were changed so that they implement these interfaces in order to make the views which use them testable in unit tests. So I am not sure if the FlexTable implements these interfaces but in case of CellTable you can use the **[HasData](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/view/client/HasData.html)** interface.

Here you can find the interfaces that are implemented by the CellTable: [Javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html)

I personally would expose the CellTable via the **[HasData](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/view/client/HasData.html)** interface, which can be used to set and retrieve the selectionModel (for selecting rows in the CellTable).
For modifying or updating the data that is displayed in the CellTable, I would use a [ListDataProvider](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/view/client/ListDataProvider.html) and store it in the Presenter.

```
@Override    
public HasData getCellTableDisplay() {
            return cellTable;
}
```

and in the constructor of the presenter 
you can create a **ListDataProvider** and use the **addDataDisplay** function to add the CellTable:

```
final ListDataProvider<String> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String>();
dataProvider.addDataDisplay(getView().getCellTableDisplay);
```

Comment: HasData is unknown class. I am using GWT 2.1.1.

Comment: According to the Javadoc HasData interface should be part of 2.1: 
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/view/client/HasData.html

Comment: Yes its kinda weird, I also checked the docs already. I will try some fix.

Comment: I wondering if you're having any problem using a ListDataProvider inside your presenter. It uses Scheduler making a plain junit test fail. Do you do anything in order to substitute the default Scheduler implementation?

Comment: That's a really good question (haven't really used Junit tests so far). As an alternative you could keep the ListDataProvider in the View and have a method like setData() in your view interface. However as far as I know most people who follow the mvp approach keep the ListDataProvider in the Presenter.

Comment: Well, the more stuff is put in the view the more useless is the MVP... :P

Comment: Well MVP is only a design pattern and thus there is not one single best implementation for MVP. It really depends on the use case. I agree that the aim should be to keep the View as dumb as possible not but by any means.

Comment: I came up against the same problem and I just moved my `dataProvider` from my `Presenter` to my `View` to enable testing. Just wondering if you found a better solution or not?